# angular-bootstrap-lightbox "invalid image" with more than four JSON "urls" values

Tags: angularjs, json, angularbootstrap-lightbox

I am trying to make use of `angular-bootstrap-lightbox` to open a modal after clicking on a `thumbnail`, and then `navigate` through that collection of images.

The issue I am having is that only the first 4 sets of images defined in the `JSON` file are opening the modal and functioning as intended. Anything after that gives me an `Invalid image` error.

Changing the order of images in the `JSON` has the previous `invalid image` working- and then whichever becomes the "last" one gives me the same error. So it's not the actual images. I have also found that adding another image or 2 to one set that's given me that error fixes it, but not always.

I've verified the correct index is being sent to the controller, I have verified that the properties for that particular object index are valid... i am just kind of scratching my head on this, as, like I've said, the first four work! So... just adding another couple of image sets ought not to make a difference, as far as I can tell.

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'Lightbox', '$http', function($scope, Lightbox, $http) {

  $scope.images = [];
  $scope.images.urls = [];

  $http.get('data/images.json').success(function(data) { 

    for(i=0;i<data.images.length;i++) {
      $scope.images[i] = data.images[i];
    }

  });    

  $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
      Lightbox.openModal($scope.images[index].urls, index);
  };

}]);
```

JSON:

```
{
   "images":[
      {
         "urls":[
            "img/DORG_01.jpg",
            "img/DORG_02.jpg",
            "img/DORG_03.jpg",
            "img/DORG_04.jpg"
         ],
         "header":"",
         "headerText":"",
         "caption":"Optional caption",
         "thumbUrl":"img/thumbs/DORG_01.jpg",
         "templateUrl":"partials/template.html"
      },
      {
         "urls":[
            "img/LW_01.jpg",
            "img/LW_02.jpg",
            "img/LW_03.jpg",
            "img/LW_04.jpg",
            "img/LW_05.jpg",
            "img/LW_06.jpg",
            "img/LW_07.jpg"
         ],
         "header":"",
         "headerText":"",
         "caption":"Optional caption",
         "thumbUrl":"img/thumbs/LW_01.jpg",
         "templateUrl":"partials/template.html"
      },
      {
         "urls":[
            "img/WSJ_01.jpg",
            "img/WSJ_02.jpg",
            "img/WSJ_03.jpg",
            "img/WSJ_04.jpg",
            "img/WSJ_05.jpg",
            "img/WSJ_06.jpg"
         ],
         "header":"",
         "headerText":"",
         "caption":"Optional caption",
         "thumbUrl":"img/thumbs/WSJ_01.jpg",
         "templateUrl":"partials/template.html"
      },
      {
         "urls":[
            "img/VW_01.jpg",
            "img/VW_02.jpg",
            "img/VW_03.jpg",
            "img/VW_04.jpg",
            "img/VW_05.jpg",
            "img/VW_06.jpg",
            "img/VW_07.jpg"
         ],
         "header":"",
         "headerText":"",
         "caption":"Optional caption",
         "thumbUrl":"img/thumbs/VW_01.jpg",
         "templateUrl":"partials/template.html"
      },
      {
         "urls":[
            "img/TP_01.jpg",
            "img/TP_02.jpg",
            "img/TP_03.jpg",
            "img/TP_04.jpg"
         ],
         "header":"",
         "headerText":"",
         "caption":"Optional caption",
         "thumbUrl":"img/thumbs/TP_01.jpg",
         "templateUrl":"partials/template.html"
      }
   ]
}
```

And HTML partial:

```
<div>
<h2>{{image.header}}</h2>
<img ng-src="{{image.thumbUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail">

<p>{{image.headerText}}</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>{{$index}}</p>
</div>
```

Much gratitude to anyone willing to take a look for me.

Comment: Ha, I'd spent quite a bit of time searching for an answer before posting this question. It seemed like no one else had had this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem was in index value. If you check the source code of Lightbox.openModal, you'll see it is looking for index inside the array of images:

```
Lightbox.openModal = function (newImages, newIndex, modalParams) {
  Lightbox.images = newImages;
  Lightbox.setImage(newIndex);
...
Lightbox.setImage = function (newIndex) {
  if (!(newIndex in Lightbox.images)) {
    throw 'Invalid image.';
  }
...
```

In my case I did not pass the newIndex value, like: Lightbox.openModal(images);

You should check that your $index is valid when it goes inside openModal function.

Comment: Daniel,

Thank for the reply. I had a similar thought, and tried logging the $index just to make sure. Each one was correct! It seems like it almost HAS to be related to the index somehow.